# JAuthentication: :__construct - Can't login in Administrator

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, login

Today I deleted 2 plugins of my Joomla 3.x and after that when I tried again to login in my administrator i could not.

The error is: `JAuthentication: :__construct`

The solution for the previous versions was to go in the DB and in the table jos_plugins set "name - Authentication - Joomla - published" to 1 from 0.

The problem is, in Joomla 3.x we don't have this table. 
What to do now to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't you have a backup? (Hint: [Akeeba Backup](http://akeebabackup.com) )You should never delete a plugin without disabling it first to see how important it is. That way you can enable it later in your database if you're unable to login.

Comment: When you say **delete**, did you uninstall them properly through the backend, or did you remove the folder for them via FTP?

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, my coworker solved that.

What he did:
Select the table:
SELECT * FROM yourDB.extensions WHERE enabled = 0 ;

Set components login, redirection and authentication to 1.

Comment: If this question is resolved, please award the green tick to the best answer so that the system deems this page resolved (and no longer bumps it to the top of the active questions pile).

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly, it is not recommended to manually delete plugins.*

Only as a last resource, when you confirm that one system plug-in is misbehaving, and you are unable to regain control by other means.

If you have deleted a core plugin, you can just download the same Joomla version  and copy the original files to the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to solve the problem is: If you have a backup of your joomla 3 database, then use the tabell _extensions. You can from phpmyadmin delete (drop)this tabell, and upload (import)a new. If you don't have a copy, the just make a new directory named "test" or what ever you will. Make a new database on your server named "test" or what ever you want.

Now upload joomla to your test directory, and install joomla there.

When it is done, go to phpadmin, choose the database "test" then you can download (export)the tabell _extensions Now go back to your original database and delete the tabell "_extensions", when your done, import the new whatevername.sql you downloaded. When import is done, you can log in to your admin panel on joomla.